# Issue with array (if (zeds[i].x == zeds[i].x))

Tags: c++

I've created a simple game in C++ in which a player must avoid being bitten by zombies to survive.

The zombies are stored as `Z` characters in an array called `zeds`.

I am trying to write a function that can check if any zombies collide, and act accordingly.

I've written this if statement:

```
for (int i; i < MAXZEDS; ++i);
    if (zeds[i].x == zeds[i].x && zeds[i].y == zeds[i].y) 
    {
            --zlives;
            updateLives();
    }
```

Obviously it doesn't work, I'm just wondering if I can somehow rewrite this to only decrement `zlives` if a zombie collides with another zombie but NOT itself.

Apologies for the title I couldn't find a better way to summarize my issue. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Won't `zeds[i].x == zeds[i].x` always be true?

Comment: It is indeed, that's my issue.

Comment: you need to create two loops not only one...

Comment: `for (int i; ` is a terribly bad idea! Shouldn't this be `for (int i = 0; `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a double loop so you can compare two different zombies.
Something like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAXZEDS - 1; ++i)
{
    // Looping from i + 1 ensures that we only test each pair once.
    for (int j = i + 1; j < MAXZEDS; ++j)
    {
        if (zeds[i].x == zeds[j].x && zeds[i].y == zeds[j].y) 
        {
            --zlives;
            updateLives();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is 2 loops.

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAXZEDS; ++i) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < MAXZEDS; ++j) {
        if (zeds[i].x == zeds[j].x && zeds[i].y == zeds[j].y) 
        {
            --zlives;
            updateLives();
        }
    }
}
```

If the object order in `zeds` is not important, and `operator<()` is defined correctly for the element type of `zeds`, then you could sort `zeds` and check consecutive elements to get lower complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Try using nested `for` loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAXZEDS; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < MAXZEDS; j++)
    {
        if (i == j) continue; // Don't compare the current zed with itself
        else if (zeds[i].x == zeds[j].x && zeds[i].y == zeds[j].y)
        {
            --zlives;
            updateLives();
        }
    }
}
```

This iterates through `zeds` twice and compares each item in the array with each other item. I am sure there are more efficient ways, but this is the simplest.